# styling the views pager

Tags: 7, views

I'm using drupal 7 and i made a view that has a pager.
Is there any way to put the pager-item (pagers number) inside any html tag?

`<ul class="pager">`
`<div>// new html tag`
`<li class="pager-current first">1</li>`
`<li class="pager-item">2</li>`
`<li class="pager-item">3</li>`
`<li class="pager-item">4</li>`
`</div>`
`<li class="pager-next">......`

Answer (score 2):

Ofcourse you can...

Make a copy of views-view.tpl.php in your theme.

Then you put your tag around the output of the $pager variable.

```
  <?php if ($pager): ?>
    <somemadeuptag>
       <?php print $pager; ?>
    </somemadeuptag>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

> *"no that is not what i looking for, i need put html tag inside $pager variable"*

You need to use **hook_pager_link()** in your theme.

Search for 'hook_pager_link' in your sites code directory to see example.

Comment: no that is not what i looking for, i need put html tag inside $pager variable

Comment: Ahhh that makes more sense, see updated answer.