# How to add a class to a pager?

Tags: 7, views, paging

I would like to add bootstrap classes to a load more pager, with the views load more module. I am currently using javascript to add it on, but the moment I change the view the classes are no longer there. I assume I have to use theme_preprocess_item_list() but I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

[image: load more pager]

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71881/styling-the-views-pager

Comment: I'm not quite sure how that helps? Do I have to use hook_pager_link()?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working by using the template_views_load_more_pager. I was just using the wrong function name. Found it in the views load more module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, got it working by using the template_views_load_more_pager. I was just using the wrong function name. Found it in the views load more module.